# Deleting parent folder msbuild

Tags: msbuild, directory, parent

Am passing the the below path as parameter to msbuild project.

"D:\Tools\TestTools\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3"

How to I delete the "Folder1" by traversing this parameter using msbuild?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the path twice:

```
<Target Name="DeleteSubDir" DependsOnTargets="">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Dir>D:\Tools\TestTools\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3</Dir>
    <DirToDelete>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('$(Dir)'))</DirToDelete>
    <DirToDelete>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('$(DirToDelete)'))</DirToDelete>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(DirToDelete)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly go two directories above:

```
<Target Name="DeleteSubDir" DependsOnTargets="">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Dir>D:\Tools\TestTools\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3</Dir>
    <DirToDelete>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(Dir)\..\..'))</DirToDelete>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(DirToDelete)" />
</Target>
```